# Best way to find a value in an object C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

Basically I have two XML files that are being deserialized into objects.
What I want to do is take the two objects and merge info from both of them based on matching ID's.

The only way I can think of doing this looks like this:

```
foreach(Computer PC in Computers)
{

    foreach(Info data in InfoTable)
    {

        if(PC.ID == data.ID){PC.Info = data.Info;}
    }
}
```

I have about 10k records so I can't imagine this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 5):

Create a mapping `Info.ID` -> `Info` using `Dictionary<int, Info>`:

```
var map = InfoTable.ToDictionary(data => data.Id);
```

and then you need just one loop:

```
foreach(Computer PC in Computers)
{
    if(map.ContainsKey(PC.ID))
    {
        PC.Info = map[PC.ID].Info;
    }
}
```

Key-lookup in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is *O(1)* operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq

```
model pc =(from cm in Computers
        join it in InfoTable on
        cm.ID equal it.ID
        select new model
        {
        info=it.info
        });
```

where model is same class as computers or your final data